# How to remove a comment (or strap line) placed by Stack Exchange that is perhaps out of date?

Tags: support

Two years ago I asked a question on Christianity Stack Exchange about the official position of the Catholic Church on same-sex marriage and civil partnerships.  After posting the question, a strap line (don't know how else to describe it) appeard saying "This post relates to a rapidly changing event."

Here is the link to my question: [What is the official Catholic position on same-sex marriage and same-sex civil partnerships?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79466/what-is-the-official-catholic-position-on-same-sex-marriage-and-same-sex-civil-p)

Perhaps that comment needs to be removed now?

Comment: "Post notice" is the term. And I've just removed it on that question.

Comment: You can flag the question and make the request that way.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Many thanks for removing the 'post notice' :-)